# Where can I find a database (sqlite, csv, etc) of Dungeons & Dragons Basic Set data?

Tags: database, sqlite, drag-and-drop

I'm writing an engine for Dungeons & Dragons Basic Set (Red and Blue Box) First Edition (1E) in Python and would like to be able to read from an existing database of what is in the players and experts guide books.

I'm looking for all the numerical data and spell data for all the classes and monsters.

I figure that something like this exists, and after plenty of Google'ing, I've found some for later editions, but not for the older ones.

It's fine if it is in some other format, but I'd like to be able to make it into a local, offline database format (like SQLite).

Answer (score 0):

**jocull** is on the right track.

Disclaimer:  I am not a lawyer.

I am sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but you are not likely to find the database you are looking for, in any *trustworthy* public place.  Dungeons & Dragons (in all of its sundry incarnations) is currently the intellectual property of [Wizards of the Coast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizards_of_the_Coast).

In the United States, copyright [does not protect gameplay rules](https://web.archive.org/web/20160411131325/http://www.copyright.gov/fls/fl108.html).  So, you could *plausibly* write your engine without violating any copyright of WotC.  However, the database you seek would most likely contain data that would be illegal to distribute, without obtaining a license from WotC.  If anyone were to distribute such a database, without authorization from WotC, that database could potentially be subject to DMCA takedown notices, and other legal action.  So, not only will you have trouble finding such a database, but if you make your own, you won't be permitted to distribute it to your users.